# How to display the top ten frequently used characters

Tags: java

i must use array to count the frequencies of characters

```
public class abc {
    public static void main ( String[] args) {
        Scanner input = new Scanner (System.in);

        String Text;
        System.out.print("Enter a text string:");
        Text=input.nextLine();
        System.out.println("Input String:");
        System.out.println(Text);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Please don't vandalise your posts.

Comment: Stop changing your question. If it's solved, and you got one more question, just open another one.

Comment: Hello Charlie, you keep trying to change your question and vandalize the answer. Please don't do that. On Stack Overflow, once questions or answers are posted, they are meant to stay for the benefit of future visitors.

Answer (score 2):

Here you have a woking code based on what you have done. There are 3 main steps :

1. Character count

I have used an HashMap mapping characters to count instead of your array. When incrementing count, you have to first check if the character is already in the map.

2. Ordering by greatest count

I use a SortedMap with reverse order, mapping the count to the list of character with this count. I populate it thanks to the previous map.
NB : this map could hav been created in the first place, but I think its easier to understand like this, and is closer to your original code.

3. Print the lettres with top 10 frequencies

In the end, just browse the sorted map to display the letters with the greatest count.

Hope it helps you, just ask questions if you do not understand some parts.

```
public static void main(final String[] args){
    final Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

    String strInText;
    // final int intLetterCount[] = new int[52];
    final Map<Character, Integer> intLetterCount = new HashMap<>();
    System.out.print("Enter a text string:");
    strInText = input.nextLine();
    strInText = strInText.trim();
    System.out.println("");
    System.out.println("Input String:");
    System.out.println("   \"" + strInText + "\"");

    for (int i = 0; i < strInText.length(); i++)
    {
        final char character = strInText.charAt(i);
        final int value = character;
        if ((value >= 65 && value <= 90) || (value >= 97 && value <= 122))
        {
            // current character count
            final Integer currentCount = intLetterCount.get(character);

            // case the character was not already present : add it to the map with count 1
            if (currentCount == null)
            {
                intLetterCount.put(character, 1);
            }
            // case the character was present. Increment count
            else
            {
                intLetterCount.put(character, currentCount + 1);
            }
        }
    }

    /*
     * Sort by character usage
     */
    // create sorted map (useful to sort easily) with reverse order to have biggest count first.
    final SortedMap<Integer, List<Character>> sortedMap = new TreeMap<>(Collections.reverseOrder());

    // for all character found, add
    for (final Map.Entry<Character, Integer> entry : intLetterCount.entrySet())
    {
        // declare current count and current char
        final int currentCount = entry.getValue();
        final Character currentChar = entry.getKey();

        // get actual list of characters with the current count.
        List<Character> charactersWithCount = sortedMap.get(currentCount);

        // if the list is null, there was no char with the current count
        if (charactersWithCount == null)
        {
            // create list, add the current char to it, put it in map
            charactersWithCount = new ArrayList<>();
            charactersWithCount.add(currentChar);
            sortedMap.put(currentCount, charactersWithCount);
        }
        // else there was other characters with the same count.
        else
        {
            // just add the new character to the list.
            charactersWithCount.add(currentChar);
        }
    }

    System.out.println("Top 10 letter counts(Number) : ");
    /*
     * print the first 10 values with higher count
     */
    final int max = 10;
    int charPrinted = 0;
    // loop through the map sorted by count
    mainLoop: for (final Map.Entry<Integer, List<Character>> entry : sortedMap.entrySet())
    {
        // loop through the list of character with the current count
        for (final Character ch : entry.getValue())
        {
            // if we have already printed more than 10 characters, break out of the main loop.
            if (charPrinted >= max)
            {
                break mainLoop;
            }

            // print char
            System.out.println(ch + " : " + entry.getKey());
            charPrinted++; // increase printed char count.
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Why _new TreeMap<>(Collections.reverseOrder())_ reverseOrder? :)
edit- have it, default order is reverse I guess :)

Answer (score 0):

It should be somewhat like this:

```
System.out.println("Top 10 letter counts(Number):");
for( int i=0; i<intLetterCount.length; i++){
   char curr = 'a'+i;
   System.out.print(curr+"-"+intLetterCount[i]+",");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try adding the character and its count to a **hash-map** so that you can print it like a key-value pair

Answer (score 0):

You can also use the stream API :

```
final String input = "I am an Unicorn";
final Map<Character, Long> collect =
        input.chars( ).mapToObj( c -> (char) c )
             .collect( Collectors.groupingBy( Function.identity( ), Collectors.counting( ) ) );

collect.forEach( ( character, count ) -> System.out.println( character + "-" + count ) );
```

Or to display the top 10 :

```
collect.entrySet( ).stream( )
       .sorted( Comparator.<Entry<Character, Long>>comparingLong( Entry::getValue ).reversed() )
       .limit( 10 )
       .forEach( ( e ) -> System.out.println( e.getKey()+ "-" + e.getValue()) );
```